# Java changing format of a double in an ArrayList<Double>

Tags: java, arraylist, double, decimalformat

I have an ArrayList that i am inputting numbers into like

```
23466012.83
23466413.39
23466411.94
```

etc.

but when i reprint them from the array after i sort them they are reprinted like this

```
2.346601283E7
2.346641339E7
2.346641194E7
```

Why does java do this and how can this be fixed? (I want the format to be the same as when it was input)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you use to print them?
You should also have a look at the [Formatter class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: notice that when you provide "23466012.83" as a double, Java is actually PARSING your string and associating it to the nearest double available for this value. So when you're printing the Double value, you're not necessarily printing the same thing you've parsed

Comment: doubles have no *format*. Only their String representations do, and so you need to change this, such as with String.format or System.out.formt, or printf...

Comment: no one will suggest using BigDecimal instead to ensure the value provided is the same value stored???? :-D

Answer (score 2):

Please review how Java handles [primitive types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_types) and their related objects. By adding a "double" (lowercase) primitive type into a List, they are converted into "Double" objects, because List in Java can only hold objects, not primitives.

Therefore when you later output the Double object, it actually uses the simple toString() method of class Double to format the line. And this is implemented in a way to print the full range of Double in a readable format, this is why it chooses the so-called [Scientific Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) with exponents display.

By using a more useful formatter, e.g. the [Formatter class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) as mentioned in the comment or the [MessageFormat class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), you can better control how the output looks like.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does java do this

Java merely prints out your `Double` values using the default number format.

> and how can this be fixed?

By explicitly specifying the desired number format.

> I want the format to be the same as when it was input

First of all, you'll need to understand that you *can't* get "the same format as when it was input" because that information is irretrievably lost. It cannot be determined by inspecting a `Double` value how many significant digits were used to parse it.

If all you need is printing with two decimal places, one way to achieve it is with this statement:

```
System.out.format("%.2f%n", 23466012.83);
```

If, by any chance, you are not bound to using `Double` as the container of your numeric values, you may also consider `BigDecimal`, which can exactly represent an arbitrary value in decimal notation. It takes a lot more memory and is a **lot** slower in computation, but for many use cases neither of those may matter much. A larger issue is that the division of `BigDecimal` is an involved process because, by default, the API will insist on producing an exact result, which will fail for things as simple as 1/3.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.format("%f%n", value);
```

Where `value` is the `double` primitive variable you want to print to sysout the screen.
Remove the `%n` if you want to continue printing on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

There are existing answers that indicate how to format the output if you want the numbers output with two decimal places, regardless of how they were input.

If you really mean "I want the format to be the same as when it was input" there is only one practical option - store the input string. You can parse it as a double or BigDecimal for validation and when you need it as input to arithmetic, but always output it using the original.